# When i run the source D:\file.sql; the following error occurs

Tags: mysql

mysql> source D:\source.sql;
ERROR: Failed to open file
'D:\source;', error: 2

Comment: Get rid of the semicolon?

Answer (score 2):

MySQL was originally built to run on Linux.
While it does run on Windows, there are some "foibles" that you need to be aware of - and the handling of backslashes is [just] one of them.

In this command ...

`mysql> source D:\source.sql`

... the backslash is taken to be "escaping" the following character (the 's'), so the path is [wrongly] interpreted as ...

`mysql> source D:source.sql`

... which, of course, is gibberish to Windows.

There are two accepted ways around this:

1. Double-up the backslash so that one escapes the other:

   `mysql> source D:\\source.sql`
2. Use forward slashes instead.
   OK, it grates a bit to Windows users, but it *is* interpreted consistently.

   `mysql> source D:/source.sql`

Answer (score 1):

The code error 2 (in your case) means that MySQL can’t find the `source.sql` file that you want to execute.

To solve this error, you need to provide the absolute path to `source.sql`.

Both forward slash (/) and back slash () should work.

For example if `source.sql` is in my desktop the command would be:

```
USE my_database;
SOURCE C:/Users/ergest/Desktop/source.sql;
```